# Word for "of or to do with groups"

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, neologisms, greek

I appreciate this is somewhat arbitrary, but humour me! I am trying to come up with a term that describes the following...

- I am working with "groups" of people. This is the informal definition, rather than, say, the mathematical definition of a "group". (Technically, I'm talking about POSIX groups of users, but in my mind, the analogy holds.)
- Entities can be associated with a group. (e.g., This play was performed by group A, that play was performed by group B, etc. The "performed by" association in this example is arbitrary and I realise "troupe" would be better here than "group", but you get the idea! In my specific case, I'm talking about the association of ownership -- "X is owned by group Y" -- but I don't think that matters.)

Thus I'm looking for an adjective that means "of or to do with groups", preferably with Greek roots.

My ultimate reason is that I'm referring to multiple entities that are associated with the same group. Sticking with English, I've come up with **homogroupic**, but it's not very satisfying (hence my question).

For example:

> This theatre's homogroupic performances were critically acclaimed.

...would mean something like:

> All performances which were performed by the same group, at this theatre, were critically acclaimed.

That single adjective being both more precise and terser.

(In the mathematical sense of a "group", both *homogroupal* and *homogroupic* appear in the literature, with the former slightly more popular. I personally prefer the sound of the *-ic* suffix, hence going for that.)

Comment: Not exactly along the lines you seem to be going for, but I would just say the contingent of theater performers was critically acclaimed. This implying that there is some underlying relation between those members of the group.

Comment: What's wrong with *this theatre **group's** performance was critically acclaimed*?

Comment: Maybe my theatre group example wasn’t the best one... My actual use case are a bunch of files and I want to describe the ones that belong to the same group succinctly.